# How to store JSON array of data into C# collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net

I have the below Json to my API - can you please suggest me how do I store these json data in to C# List or collection

```
{
  "AccountDetails": [
    {
      "InNumber": "123453333",
      "OutNumber": "125666666"
    },
    {
      "InNumber": "2345543334",
      "OutNumber": "4556666667"
    },
    {
      "InNumber": "9793543333",
      "OutNumber": "2345543333"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried below , but it snot working , kindly let me know if there is any better performance approach

```
var persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Member>>(AccountDetails);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("InNumber", typeof(System.String)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("OutNumber", typeof(System.String)));
    

    foreach (var item in persons)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["InNumber"] = item.InNumber;
        dr["OutNumber"] = item.OutNumber;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

Comment: Create a class called `AccountDetail` with two string properties,  `InNumber` and `OutNumber`. Then create a type that has a property named `AccounDetails` that is a `List<AccountDetail>` (let's call that class `Account`). Now you can deserialize into an instance of `Account`. Note that your JSON does not represent a list, it represents an object with a single property that happens to be a list. Do not use DataTables

Comment: OK, thank you for the suggestion , I am able to list the all inNumbers and outnumbers in a list  but its difficult to identify which is InNumber is tagged to Outnumber - can you please help me, how do I display records - such way that both the associated numbers can be easily identified , because at the end I need to to store InNumber and corresponding Outnumber in DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you've shown is an Object with a Property called AccountDetails that contains your array. Note how the outer Json is surrounded by { } and not [ ] which is why you're seeing that error.

This is a duplicate of [Deserialize Json into C# Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45066930/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-collection)

You could solve that, for instance, like this:

[working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n15KRR)

or you parse the collection out of the JSON Object (the answer below)

Create an object that contains a list of AccountDetails

```
public class ListContainingObject
{
    public List<Member> AccountDetails;
}
```

deserialize to that

```
var listcontainingobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListContainingObject>(jsontext);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/NXCrDC

Comment: Thank you for your time - when I try this approach I am getting records like below :123453333
125666666
2345543334
4556666667
9793543333
2345543333 in this list its difficult to identify which is InNumber is tagged to Outnumber  - can you please help me, how do I display records - such way that both the associated numbers can be easily identified , because at the end I need to to store InNumber  and corresponding Outnumber in DB

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sDPJbn

Answer (score 2):

This is an elaboration of my comment.

Here I create a class to hold your account details:

```
public class AccountDetail
{
    public string InNumber { get; set; }
    public string OutNumber { get; set; }
}
```

But, your JSON data represents an object that has a single property that represents a collection of these, so I need this as well:

```
public class Account
{
    public List<AccountDetail> AccountDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can deserialize your data into an `Account` instance:

```
public static void Test()
{
    const string data = @"
         {
          ""AccountDetails"": [
            {
                ""InNumber"": ""123453333"",
                ""OutNumber"": ""125666666""
            },
            {
                ""InNumber"": ""2345543334"",
                ""OutNumber"": ""4556666667""
            },
            {
                ""InNumber"": ""9793543333"",
                ""OutNumber"": ""2345543333""
            }
          ]
        }";
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(data);
}
```

In a reply comment to my comment, you say:

> I am able to list the all inNumbers and outnumbers in a list but it's difficult to identify which is InNumber is tagged to Outnumber. How do I display records - such way that both the associated numbers can be easily identified , because at the end I need to to store InNumber and corresponding Outnumber in DB.

I'm not quite following.  You have a list of `AccountDetail` objects, each of which has an `InNumber` / `OutNumber` pair.  That's easily inserted into a database using any modern database access mechanism (or, just a loop around an `INSERT` statement).  You don't show your database access code, so I can't tell you.

What I can tell you is that I nearly never use DataTables unless I'm working on *really* old code.

Since it appears you *really* want it in a `DataTable`, add this code to the end of `Test` (after the line that starts `var result =`):

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("InNumber", typeof(System.String)));
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("OutNumber", typeof(System.String)));

foreach (var accountDetail in result.AccountDetails)
{
    DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
    dr["InNumber"] = accountDetail.InNumber;
    dr["OutNumber"] = accountDetail.OutNumber;

    dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want a DataTable

```
DataTable dt = JObject.Parse(jsonString)["AccountDetails"].ToObject<DataTable>();
```

if you want a List

```
List<AccountDetail> persons = JObject.Parse(jsonString)["AccountDetails"].ToObject<List<AccountDetail>>();

public class AccountDetail
{
    public string InNumber { get; set; }
    public string OutNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,  difficult to identify which is InNumber is tagged to Outnumber - can you please help me, how do I display records - such way that both the associated numbers can be easily identified , because at the end I need to to store InNumber and corresponding Outnumber in DB columns

Comment: @user613400 Each record has only two properties "InNumber" and "OutNumber" .  And one is taged to another. What is the problem? Your question is not clear

Comment: @user613400 If you don't understand what is the  c# class and what is the property , and what is the instance of the class, how are you going to create  the code to save data to db?